# Using more than one GPO

Tags: group-policy, mappeddrive

I understand that GPO conflicts are resolved from bottom to top, so if two policies do the same thing only one will be applied.

Now if I want to map drives using a GPO, so 3 drives (E:,F:,G:) are mapped for all employees and one additionnal (H:) is mapped for Admins only.  Can I use a GPO to map 3 drives for all and then use another GPO to map one more drive for the Admin?  Or is this considered a conflict and only one of the two GPOs will be applied?

Comment: I wanted to know this because it did not seem to work.  But I found out that a windows update could be causing this problem:  http://borncity.com/win/2016/06/16/update-kb3159398-breaks-group-policy-in-windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you can do what you're asking. The GPOs will not conflict if they are mapping different drives. We have this exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be that complicated. You can use a single GPO and define all of the mapped drives using Group Policy Preferences and Item-level targeting.

Answer (score 0):

There's several solutions for this depending on your OU structure.

For example if you have:

> -Users
>
> > |-Admins

Where Admins is an OU contained by the Users OU.

You can apply the users GPO to the users OU and the Admin GPO to the admin OU.

This way by inheritance the users GPO will get applied also to the Admins OU but the admin GPO won't get applied to the users OU because is on a lower level.

Other way would be if you have both users and Admins on the same OU.

You can apply both GPO's to this OU but filter the application by group or specific users with the settings on the Admin GPO or vice versa.